# Присвоить класс CSS ссылке

Tags: php, css

Есть такой код. Задача: присвоить класс CSS ссылке. Как это лучше сделать?

```
<a data-toggle="tab" href="#module-'.$rendermodule->id.'" class="btn"> </a> Вот так?

foreach($modules as $rendermodule) {
        echo '<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#module-'.$rendermodule->id.'" >'.$rendermodule->title.'</a></li>';
```

Comment: а что ты хочешь получить в итоге то?

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы ссылка отличалась от друших внешне, поэтому и присваиваю другой стиль.

Comment: @Grosso2020, у вас правильно всё написано вначале, но если вы будете присваивать класс в цикле, то он будет у всех ссылок, чтобы этого не было, вам нужно придумать условие, при котором этот класс будет у ссылки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[href*='#module']{
    border: 1px solid #bbb; /* Ваши стили */
}
```